# javascript and css not loading properly in WordPress site

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I managed to make my code working via codepen as you can see if you visit the link [here](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gmyoWM?editors=1111)

Now trying to implement on a WordPress test site it looks like my javascript is not working as well as the fontawesome is not being loaded properly.
[Here is the link for the test site](http://wordpressdev.burnnotice.co.za/)

Here it is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var txtFromDate, txtToDate;
  $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtFromDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#txtTo").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      txtToDate = selected;
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });

  $('.submit-here').click(function() {
    // var link = day_1+month_1+year;
    var date1 = $("#txtFrom").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_1  = date1.getDate(),  
        month_1 = date1.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_1 =  date1.getFullYear();

    var date2 = $("#txtTo").datepicker('getDate'),
        day_2  = date2.getDate(),  
        month_2 = date2.getMonth() + 1,              
        year_2 =  date2.getFullYear(); 

    var where = $('#selection :selected').text();
    var people = $('#people :selected').text();

    console.log('www.lekkeslaap.co.za/akkommodasie-in/'+where+'?q='+where+'&start='+day_1+'+'+month_1+'+'+year_1+'&end='+day_2+'+'+month_2+'+'+year_2+'&pax='+people);   
  });
});
```

And here it is for my functions.php:

```
function testsite_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'testsite-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'testsite-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'testsite-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testsite_scripts' );

function testsite_load_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font_extra', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/start/jquery-ui.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'calendario', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'calendario', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/calendario.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testsite_load_scripts' );
```

Comment: try to run this code "$(window).on('load', function () {
alert("js works"');
});"  if it does not run then replace $ with jQuery and run again.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses jQuery in a noConflict mode. Use it like this:

```
(function($){

    /**
     * Immediate execution
     */
    console.log();

    /**
     * When DOM is ready
     */
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });

    /**
     * When all content is loaded
     */
    $(window).load(function(){

    }); // window.load END

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited my functions.php and it works now

```
function testsite_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'testsite-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/start/jquery-ui.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin_script', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'testsite-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'calendario', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/calendario.js', array('jquery'), '20151215', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'testsite-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testsite_scripts' );
```